# How to make sure a php script never runs twice

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a php mailer which gets POST data from a javascript application xmlhttp request.

It works fine with about 50 contacts but I just tested it on 150 test email addresses and mid way through the script hit the max execution time (because I put a delay after sending each mail) and then it automatically restarted the script with the same data and started sending mail from the first contact onwards.

I was worried it was going to loop indefinately, but it stopped after hitting the max exec time in the second run. I closed the javascript application during the second run, so maybe that had something to do with it stopping.

I'm going to either increase the max execution time or parse the php chunks of data instead, but I need to make sure that this can never happen again because in a real world run I can never have two emails sent to the same person.

Is there any other case where the php script might run twice and is there a sure fire way to ensure it can never happen?

Comment: This is a far more complex problem than it seems.  You need to track the last time it ran, and / or the last time it sent an e-mail to a person, and when you're executing, check to ensure it hasn't run in the past X hours, or hasn't sent to that person before (or hasn't sent to them in the past X hours).

Comment: Did you consider using Swiftmailer? It should have no problem sending that amount of emails.

Comment: _is there any other case where the php script might run twice_; yes, if you run it twice. You need to check why the script ran twice.

Comment: @cale_b, ah I see, good idea. I've already built a logging system so I could work with that.

Comment: @SalmanA, the only reason I can think of why the script ran twice is possibly because of cashed POST data? I'm not sure how it works exactly, maybe when the script fails because of max execution time the server runs it again with cashed POST data. It's shared hosting so I'm not sure.

Comment: @user2721465: No, I never heard of such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you read mails from file you need cut them off from it or make list with sended mails and compare with source list.
Moreover would be better to use database with columns like id,target,sent(true/false),datetime and update it after mail successful sends

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your e-mail addresses are in some sort of database, making the answer fairly straightforward.

Add another common of DATETIME to your table, and update it every time the scripts sends an e-mail to that contact.

Right before you send the email, get that stamp and compare it to a human value, DATETIME of previous and current message. If the last message was sent after the most recent was issued, don't send it.

If I was wrong in assuming there is no database.... I highly suggest you get a database.